# "Object variable or With block variable not set" when closing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fix some code, but have no experience with the Microsoft Visual Basic. When closing an active workbook I am getting the runtime error '91', the code which is causing the error is:

```
Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
appExcel.Visible = True

' More VBA code here, I can post if it would be necessary but I would 
' assume this is enough code to see the problem

appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
appExcel.Quit
```

I am assuming that at this point the Excel active workbook would close and don't know why this code isn't doing this

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkBook.Close SaveChanges:=False` and `appExcel.Quit`.

Comment: Do you ever add an workbook to your excel application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because there is no **Workbooks** open in that instance at that moment.

If you try this code, you will see that you will not get an error

```
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Visible = True

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
appExcel.Workbooks.Add '<~~ Add a temp workbook
appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

To handle that use this

```
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Visible = True

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
If appExcel.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Best is to work with `Objects` so that you do not close the wrong workbook by mistake. For example

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Add
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close
Set wb = Nothing
```

Comment: Put a break on `If appExcel.Workbooks.Count` and see what value do you get for `appExcel.Workbooks.Count`

Comment: The value I'm getting for appExcel.Workbooks.Count is one (doing ````?appExcel.Workbooks.Close```` in the immediate window), appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close is highlighted yellow when debug is launched

Comment: Try this `If appExcel.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then appExcel.Workbooks(1).Close`